# Python unittest AssertionError: 0 != []

Tags: python, python-unittest, assertion

I'm new to Python unittest and I'm trying to access this list:

```
    def setUp(self):
        self.customers = [
            {"name": "Mary", "pets": [], "cash": 1000},
            {"name": "Alan", "pets": [], "cash": 50},
            {"name": "Richard", "pets": [], "cash": 100},
        ]
```

to do this test:

```
    def test_customer_pet_count(self):
        count = get_customer_pet_count(self.customers[0])
        self.assertEqual(0, count)
```

I've created this function:

```
def get_customer_pet_count(customer_number):
    if ["pets"] == 0 or ["pets"] == []:
        return 0
    return customer_number["pets"]
```

But I keep getting this error:
`AssertionError: 0 != []`

Can someone help explain what I'm doing wrong in the function please?

Comment: the test condition can never be true... and `customer_number["pets"]` is an empty list, not a number

Comment: `["pets"] == 0 or ["pets"] == []` can never be true. `["pets"]` is a literal list with one element.

Comment: you may try `self.assertEqual(False, bool(count))`

Comment: It means that `get_customer_pet_count` returns an empty list, instead of 0, which the test expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at this part, the `get_customer_pet_count` function:

```py
def get_customer_pet_count(customer_number):
    if ["pets"] == 0 or ["pets"] == []:
        return 0
    return customer_number["pets"]
```

First, you're not passing it a "customer number" or index, you're passing it the actual customer dictionary. Like `{"name": "Mary", "pets": [], "cash": 1000}`.

Second, this comparison: `["pets"] == 0` checks "if a list with one element, the string 'pets', is equal to the number 0". This can never be true. A list will never be ***equal to*** a number.*

The next comparison `["pets"] == []` is checking "if the list with one element, the string 'pets' is equal to an empty list". That can also never be true. An empty list cannot be equal to a non-empty list.

If you wrote it as `def get_customer_pet_count(customer):` then it might be clearer. You're passing it the dictionary with the customer *info*, not the customer *number*. Also, your function says *`pet_count`* so it should be the **length of the pets list**:

```py
def get_customer_pet_count(customer):
    return len(customer["pets"])
```

<sub>*Ignoring user-defined types faking that behaviour.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down and your explanation, I didn't realise empty list couldn't equal to a number so this has helped a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

self.customers[0] is empty list []. You should use len(self.customers[0]) or modify the function like this:

```
def get_customer_pet_count(customer_number):
    if customer_number == 0 or customer_number == []:
        return 0
    return customer_number
```